# R: httr SOAP POST request for xml return error - "media type is unsupported"

Tags: r, soap, rcurl, httr

I'm trying to use R script to make SOAP query. Expecting xml file response. The POST request returns a `415` error. I am struggling how to phrase it right in R.

I tried in httr:

```
library(httr)
library(xml2)
library(RCurl)


headers = "{'content-type': 'text/xml'}"  #Also tried'application/xml; charset=utf-8'}"
body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetGenericData xmlns="http://...">
      <QueryMessage xmlns="http:.../...">
        <Query>
          <DataWhere xmlns="http://.../...">
            <And>
              <DataSet>ABC</DataSet>
              <Dimension id="ABC">abc</Dimension>
            </And>
          </DataWhere>
        </Query>
      </QueryMessage>
    </GetGenericData>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'

#headers <- c('application/xml; charset=utf-8')
#names(headers) <- 'content-type'

response = POST("http://exampleWebService?op=GetGenericData", 
                config = list(add_headers(.headers = headers)) ,
                body = body, 
                content_type(".xml"),
                encode = 'raw',
                accept_xml(),
                type = 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8',
                # content_type_xml(),
                authenticate(":", ":", "ntlm"))
                )
```

Then the query response status would be error:

```
> response[["all_headers"]][[1]]
$status
[1] 401

> response[["all_headers"]][[2]]
$status
[1] 415

> http_type(response)
[1] "text/html"
> http_error(response)
[1] TRUE

>content(response)

No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
{xml_document}
<html>
[1] <body><p>The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported.</p></body>
```

The http_type(response) will always return[1] "text/html", no matter how I changed the header. It seems my client request is not process correctly on server side?
What would be the right header/encoding/content-type??? Any hint?

---

Comment: Is the body xml content phrased correctly? Triple quotes seems unnecessary but if I put triple quotes around body variable, the response type will become "application/xml +soap"

Comment: You need to provide us with a server that we can use and try to fix the error on. We can't help if we can't reproduce the errors you got. Thanks.

Comment: This is same error in java `media type is unsupported` I got when I integrating the susiAir soap request. I have solved by passing header like this  `"text/xml; charset=utf-8"`. I have not tried in R but give a try.

Comment: hi check my answer , if it help's you

Answer (score 0):

**1**  maybe  its the `accept_xml()`  the `Accept:` header by default is application/xml try  `accept("application/soap+xml")`

**2** or change the context type to text/plain  to see if your server is set to handle xml MIME or not see the response is it 200  or  415  then you will know where your problem is server response   or   client request

**3** maybe header is case sensitive `Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8`  in your server

Comment: They didn't work... :( I switch back and forth from 'txt/plain' to 'text/xml', or ''application/soap+xml', the error persist. How to interpret the response[["all_headers"]][[1]]
$status
[1] 401  VS > response[["all_headers"]][[2]]
$status
[1] 415?  Why it said both "unauthorized" and wrong media type?

Comment: hi please try first sending EMPTY XML BODY  with same headers in your code ,    
 also try to send EMPTY BODY with same  headers in your code   ,                        try the headers in my answer with EMPTY body ,  that maybe give answer on the server what  headers it accepts and what headers are correct .